# Work arounds or naming the problem for this message: 'do not have permission to open the application "ECGWorkbench'

Tags: java, permissions

I'm trying open this application: [http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/~lucag/](http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/%7Elucag/)
(It's a research tool might might be great for my work so I really want to access it).

I'm running big sur on a 2014 mac book pro. It has Java 8 (I'm assuming that this is the 'Java Virtual Machine' which is specified in the instructions).

When I try and open the app I get the message:
"You do not have permission to open the application "ECGWorkbench'.
Contact your computer or network administrator for assistance."

I've tried everything on these two threads:
[Can't run app because of permission in Big Sur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64842819/cant-run-app-because-of-permission-in-big-sur)
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/666611?page=3
I've tried opening the app on a mac which hadn't been upgraded to big sur. I can't get hold of a Windows or Linux computer.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a work around? I'm not a programer so bear with this question but if the app is written in Java and I had the code could I execute it? The folder with the app in had lots of other files. Or if I installed Linux in a virtual environment on my mac could I then open the Linux version of the app?
2. If it can't be fixed I'm going to try to contact the developers. The project doesn't seem to be very active so I'm not convinced they'd be interested in updating the app. If I could suggest what amendment they need to make or at least say why it's not working they might be more willing to help me out. Can anyone suggest what I could say to them? Something along the lines of 'I can't open the app because of XYZ, could you change the ABC' would be perfect. The NTL (neural theory of language) project created the app but they are part of the ICSI (international computer science institute) at berkley so I'm assuming they know what code is etc.

Thank you.

Rachel

Answer (score 0):

I've been a little late with my reply, but I hope my solution will help you.

I had the same issue with eclipse (i need it for study things), so i opened my terminal and typed the following command...

```
codesign --force --deep --sign -/Application/Eclipse.app
```

After a reasign everything works fine for me.