# "GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye."

Tags: macos, electron, electron-builder

I'm experimenting with building a Windows and Mac OS app using Electron and have hit a snag.

In short, if I try to run the application directly with Electron on Mac OS Big Sur (as opposed to building a Mac app and then running that) I get the following error returned:

```
[35941:0821/171720.038162:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(415)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
```

I am running directly with Electron using the following in my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "test": "electron main.js",
  ...
}
```

So far the only Mac OS environment I have access to is Big Sur so haven't tried this on earlier versions of Mac OS but from Googling it seems this error may be related to Big Sur's tightened security/sandbox constraints -- but I am guessing about that.

In any case, after some Googling several suggestions indicated trying to run without the app sandbox, i.e. adding this to `main.js`:

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('no-sandbox');
```

That's all well and good and works.

However, if I ever want to build and distribute a signed Mac app targeting the Mac App store or a just a signed, sandboxed DMG or PKG installer, then this won't be suitable.

If I remove the above `no-sandbox` command from `main.js` and specify the app sandbox in my entitlements `plist` as shown below the resulting signed app will not run:

```
<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
<true/>
```

The app tries to open and just closes. I can try running at the command line with `open <appname>.app` but this throws the following error in the console:

```
The application cannot be opened for an unexpected reason, error=Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10826 "kLSNoLaunchPermissionErr: User doesn't have permission to launch the app (managed networks)" UserInfo={_LSFunction=_LSLaunchWithRunningboard, _LSLine=2561, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd3c9c13db0 {Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Launch failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Launch failed., NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd3c9c158e0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=153 "Unknown error: 153" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Launchd job spawn failed with error: 153}}}}}
```

If I build a signed app with `no-sandbox` enabled, the app will run just fine on Big Sur using `open <appname>.app`.

I have tried my best through Google, Stack Overflow, etc to diagnose this but am not getting anywhere. Here's to hoping the Stack Overflow community can provide me the critical clue to solving this.

For further context, I created a new, empty Electron application and followed the [Electron Quick Start Guide](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/quick-start) to the section where it describes creating an empty `main.js` which technically should allow the Electron app to start -- but it won't. The same error describe above re the GPU gets thrown even without instantiating a `BrowserWindow` or writing any custom code of my own.

NEW UPDATE: I set these environment variables to true and then tried running the app with `npm start`:

- `ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING`
- `ELECTRON_DEBUG_NOTIFICATIONS`
- `ELECTRON_ENABLE_STACK_DUMPING`

The result is more detailed error output:

```
[48836:0823/165857.676747:ERROR:icu_util.cc(179)] icudtl.dat not found in bundle
[48836:0823/165857.676838:ERROR:icu_util.cc(243)] Invalid file descriptor to ICU data received.
[48778:0823/165857.677376:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1003)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=5
[48778:0823/165857.677430:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1317)] The GPU process has crashed 1 time(s)
[48850:0823/165857.827224:ERROR:icu_util.cc(179)] icudtl.dat not found in bundle
[48848:0823/165857.827255:ERROR:icu_util.cc(179)] icudtl.dat not found in bundle
[48850:0823/165857.827341:ERROR:icu_util.cc(243)] Invalid file descriptor to ICU data received.
[48848:0823/165857.827358:ERROR:icu_util.cc(243)] Invalid file descriptor to ICU data received.
[48778:0823/165857.827836:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1003)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=5
[48778:0823/165857.827875:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1317)] The GPU process has crashed 2 time(s)
... repeats until the GPU processes crashes 9 times ...
[48778:0823/165903.080134:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(415)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
```

Haven't had time to do the research as to what ICU refers to but thought I would update with this info.

ANOTHER UPDATE: all this has been done on Mac OS Big Sur which is my main development machine. Trying this on a Windows 10 machine, using the same Electron code, dependencies, etc and things work fine. So the problem is either related to Mac OS Big Sur or a specific local issue on my development machine which I cannot identify. Any suggestions on how to diagnose this will be much appreciated.

ONE MORE UPDATE: Based on a guess, I created a new user on my mac, took the code in there and it ran perfectly. So -- this probably means that I need to find something installed in my profile or some corruption in my own profile/settings that is breaking things. As always, any suggestions appreciated it.

Comment: "Verily I say, all hope is lost."

Comment: I am definitely losing hope at the absence of any real insight into this in the google-sphere.

Comment: `if (fallback_modes_.empty()) {.. intentionallyCrash..)` found in [ChromiumSource:415->1705](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/content/browser/gpu/gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc).
It can be called from 4 different functions and seems to be just NOT a fallback.. it is just very very ugly google code! Means it is not a sandbox problem but fallback problem. Check your GPU modes setup

Comment: And more precise.. `// With Vulkan or Metal, GL might be blocked, so make sure we don't fallback to it later.` just saying MacOS BigSur does not support GL anymore. You will have to read up how Electron handles this change..

Comment: Just for a little more context for anyone who might have suggests (I'm still seeing what I can learn about the suggestion from @OlSen so suggestions about that are appreciate too). I created a pristine Electron app and followed the Electron Quick Start Guide [link](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/quick-start) to the where it says to create an empty main.js. At that point I am already triggering the error described here -- no need to have a window instantiated or any custom code.

Comment: did you notice the surrounding bracelets in `package.json` in the Quick Start Guide. Not sure if that matters.. Your code above doesnt have such. And ye GL means OpenGL but in case of Electron which is using WKWebView's it sould be WebGL. WebGL is still supported of course, it is still integral part of webkit. So the problem seems to be much more simple rooted.

Comment: Thanks. Yes -- this is just a one line extract from my `package.json` to show the particular relevant line.

Answer (score 15):

In my case, I got this to work using command line switch, --in-process-gpu, or:

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('in-process-gpu');
```

There's also an extensive list of Chromium switches here that you can try at:
https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Yeah, the whole hardened runtime thing is just such an awful, awful mess! Now to figure out the next crash!

Comment: This was what I needed to get fortinet client ```forticlient``` to work on Ubuntu linux

Answer (score 3):

So -- partial answer. I think I've found the solution to this error:

```
GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
```

My development directories are all on a file system accessed via a symbolic link. As soon as I moved the folder for this app to my my home directory (no symlinks involved) I could launch with `npm start` without needing to enable `no-sandbox` and without seeing this error or the errors related to `icudtl.dat`.

I haven't yet determined if the problem described with the error below when launching the packaged app is related/solved:

```
The application cannot be opened for an unexpected reason, error=Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10826 "kLSNoLaunchPermissionErr: User doesn't have permission to launch the app (managed networks)" UserInfo={_LSFunction=_LSLaunchWithRunningboard, _LSLine=2561, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd3c9c13db0 {Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Launch failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Launch failed., NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd3c9c158e0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=153 "Unknown error: 153" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Launchd job spawn failed with error: 153}}}}}
```

That said, it is a big step forward.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64842819/cant-run-app-because-of-permission-in-big-sur

Comment: @iLuvLogix Thanks but had seen and tried that already. Didn't work. Seems to be somehow related to entitlements and/or code signing (i.e. maybe not the right cert being used).

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar issue on a linux machine with an electron app. The answer in this github [issue](https://github.com/balena-io/etcher/issues/3639) helped me.

Using `--disable-gpu-sandbox` flag with electron apps solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem seems to be that the Mac OS sandbox is preventing the GPU process to spawn properly.

You can specify a variety of entitlements when packaging your application, but not all entitlements are created equally, especially entitlements that want access to the keychain, secure enclave and TouchID.

If you're specifying a `provisioning profile` - make sure that all those entitlements are only in the original file, keep your inherited entitlements empty or to the bare minimum. In my case, I had the `keychain-access-groups` specified in my inherited entitlements which was a painful lesson to learn. Removing it made the builds not crash!

I believe in your case it's likely that you tried to access files outside of the application itself which might have caused the sandbox to prevent opening the GPU processes.

Comment: This is widespread and happens on Linux too, I don't think it's about Mac OS being fussy.

Comment: It's generally a problem with sandboxes, or security settings though

Answer (score 0):

I know the OP reported this against MacOS, but on my Windows 10 VM I used the following instructions to create the electron-quick-start app…

```
net use T: \\busdata\company\BrianT
T:
cd \Development\Sandbox\electron
"C:\Users\thomasb\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-2.9.15\resources\app\git\cmd\git.exe" clone https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start
cd electron-quick-start
npm install && npm start
```

…and then electron wrote error messages to the console, the same errors as those reported by the OP:

```
[5796:1025/121431.238:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(969)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=18
[5796:1025/121431.328:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(441)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
```

An earlier answer mentioned **symbolic links**, and to investigate that further I xcopied the entire electron-quick-start folder down from T: (a remapped network folder) to C: (my local disk).

When I then ran **npm start** in the folder that I'd copied down to C: **there was no error**.

Looks like electron is being fussy about where the source files live.

Comment: Your security policy probably doesn't allow spawning processes from executables that are on a network share. Anyone with access to the network could replace the executable, so the OS is probably stopping it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Issue when running the files off of a server such as a nas, but moving files to local storage solved the issue.