# Electron window crashing after launch on windows

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I just started working in electron.js , when i try to launch the app using "npm start" it shows a window for briefe secound than it crashes giving me this error log :

```
[0825/174253.795:ERROR:trace_logging_minimal_win.cc(78)] Provider resistration failure
[5644:0825/174254.255:ERROR:block_files.cc(441)] Failed to open C:\Users\rabah\AppData\Roaming\datacolector\GPUCache\data_0
[5644:0825/174254.260:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(947)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=17
[0825/174254.298:ERROR:trace_logging_minimal_win.cc(78)] Provider resistration failure
[5644:0825/174254.379:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(947)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=17
[5644:0825/174254.432:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(947)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=17
[5644:0825/174254.494:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(947)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=17
[5644:0825/174254.512:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(947)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=17
[5644:0825/174254.526:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(947)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=17
[5644:0825/174254.553:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(947)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=17
[5644:0825/174254.558:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(947)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=17
[5644:0825/174254.567:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(947)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=17
[5644:0825/174254.585:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(440)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
```

my code :

main.js :

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

const createWindow = () => {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600
  })

  win.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
})
```

package.json :

```json
{
  "name": "datacolector",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Firas Roggai",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^23.1.3"
  }
}
```

- I tried installing older versions of electron but it still gives me the same error

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68874940/gpu-process-isnt-usable-goodbye)